# HQL query ignores time portion of the Date object

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have problem with HQL where I am setting the query parameters. One of them is Date. When I debug the code there is Date with time entering the method. I set the parameter using `setParameter(timestamp, new Timestamp(date.getTime()))` or `query.setTimestamp`...etc etc I used many combinations...

When I use p6spy to examine the SQL comming from app to the DB there is only `'29-Jan-21'` or other date without time.

I am using hibernate 5.1.0 final and postgre DB. I'll be glad for any help.

Example:

```
Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT user FROM UserEntity cr WHERE user.userStatus.id = :statusId AND :timestamp >= user.valid_to");
```

This is how I tried to set the timestamp parameter:

```
query.setParameter("timestamp", new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
query.setParameter("timestamp", date, TimestampType.INSTANCE);
query.setTimestamp("timestamp", date);
query.setTimestamp("timestamp", new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

Problem is that the generated SQL replace timestamp by `'29-Jan-21'` or other date I choose but without time. The `date` parameter comes to the method from UI and it contains full date with time.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the necessary portion of your code that helps us understand your problem. Show your queries and different approaches to solve them and don't forget what result you are actually expecting. Then I am pretty sure that you'll get an answer pretty fast :)

Comment: After some time I am back with the "solution". I thought that the portion of date is lost just because I used P6SPY framework in specific version that did not log the full Date - so the app was working just fine...:)